# How to write to $BASH_ENV with echo command using an existing environment variable?

Tags: linux, bash, circleci

I'm building an application with CircleCI and I'm looking to echo an environment variable to the $BASH_ENV so that it will persist between CircleCI steps.

A working example of this is:

```
echo 'export TEST_NAME=$( cat dockername.txt )' >> $BASH_ENV
```

Which will allow the TEST_NAME to be correctly loaded in the following CircleCI steps. I'm now looking to do the same but with the variable being equal to an existing environment variable.

```
export VAR=FOO
echo $VAR // outputs 'FOO'

echo 'export TOKEN=$VAR' >> $BASH_ENV 
// TOKEN outputs null in same and subsequent steps. I need it to equal FOO
```

I've tried every variation of syntax for this to work but I can't seem to crack it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

`echo "export TOKEN=${VAR}" >> $BASH_ENV`

Use double quotes to have the variable evaluated. The braces aren't necessary but are good practice.

https://devhints.io/bash